# I need to recover a partition after failed resize attempt

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, partition-recovery, repair

Okay so i had one NTFS partition and i wanted to resize it, but while resizing it with partition magic some error occurred and now i am not able to enter in my partition anymore.
I have slackware 13 also and i tried mounting the partition from there but it didn't succeed.

One friend of mine came to my house with some live-cd os called backtrack3 and when he booted from cd, he was able to mount the damaged partition - and was able to read/write on it anywhere. I saw my files, they are all there, so nothing's erased just the partition is somehow damaged. But strange thing was that from backtrack we weren't able to mount some of the working partitions of my comp, and we could mount the damaged one.

So i am asking for some help here: My files are all there, and i saw them from backtrack. What can i do to fix the partition so it would be usable from windows/slackware again ? Please tell me anything you've got because i have some important data on it.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/128043/recover-files-after-unsuccesfull-partitioning

Comment: Try getdataback http://runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm.  Run the trial and browse your files to verify data integrity (it will even let you view photos) for free, but it will not allow recovery until you pay USD 80.

Answer (score 1):

If backtrack can mount and read/write the partition, then use it. Use a USB-Stick or any other medium you've got to backup your data and recreate the partition.

Otherwise, have a look at [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).