# How to undo 'create partition primary' command of diskpart

Tags: windows, data-recovery, partition-recovery, diskpart

I was trying to recover my pendrive as it was showing 0 bytes allocated space, and I came across some information about using the diskpart command to format it.

For the worse I selected a wrong volume and started the process; I selected my hard drive and typed in 'create partition primary'. Now I cannot see my drives except for the local disk: C, in which my OS is installed.  :(  Please help me; I have no prior knowledge about this, yet I've toiled my hands and now I am stuck ... the data is very important ...

Thanks in advance for your help!

*Email removed*

Comment: It might help if you told us a little bit more about your system; e.g., what OS are you running.  Also, see [Recover files from deleted partition](http://superuser.com/questions/178028/recover-files-from-deleted-partition).

Comment: @Scott: Seems to be windows, going by the command name, drive letter and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help in recovering partition](http://superuser.com/questions/133491/help-in-recovering-partition) and many more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover files after unsuccessful partitioning](http://superuser.com/questions/128043/recover-files-after-unsuccessful-partitioning)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an external hdd or something to copy your data to?

PhotoRec will scan and recover files however it may or may not be able to recover the file names.

Many other utilities exist.  RStudio  Recuva and dozens more.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool [EaseUs partition recovery](http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/)(free), for recover the partition.

> EaseUs Partition Recovery is a free tool that can recover and restore
>   lost or damaged partitions in many cases. It can recover partitions on
>   most hard disks, including IDE, ATA, SATA, and SCSI drives and FAT,
>   NTFS, and EXT formats, for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.